# Unexpected behavior from ternary operator

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

When I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void f1() {
    map<int, int> m;
    m[5] = m.find(5) == m.end() ? 1 : 2;
    cout << m[5] << endl;
}
void f2() {
    map<int, int> m;
    if (m.find(5) == m.end())
        m[5] = 1;
    else
        m[5] = 2;
    cout << m[5] << endl;
}
int main() {
    f1();
    f2();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
2
1
```

Why am I getting wrong output when I am using ternary operator?

Comment: You're doing too many things in the same line. I strongly recommend against that.

Answer (score 2):

The order of function calls is indeterminate and affecting your results.  Consider:

```
void f1()
{
    map<int, int> m;
    int& result = m[5]; // creates m[5]
    auto it = m.find(5); // finds the empty m[5] created above
    int value = (it == m.end())? 1: 2;
    result = value;
    std::cout << m[5] << std::endl;
}
```

This is a perfectly legal implementation of the code you wrote.

There's nothing wrong with the ternary operator.  This would work just fine:

```
bool notfound = (m.find(5) == m.end());
m[5] = notfound? 1: 2;
```

The important thing is whether `m[5]` could possibly be evaluated before `m.find(5)`.

Answer (score -1):

In this statement

```
m[5] = m.find(5) == m.end() ? 1 : 2;
```

you created object m[5] by placing it in the left side of the assignment. So m.find(5) != m.end() because m[5] already exists.

In fact there is the **undefined behaviour** because the order of evaluation of the left and the right operands of the assignment is not specified.

Comment: It's not undefined behavior here, since these operators are function calls, and function calls cannot overlap.  So there is no data race.  The order of the function calls is indeterminate, however.

Comment: @Ben Voigt There is an assignment operator. Either the right operand can be evaluated first or the left operand. So there is undefined behaviour.

Comment: No, there is not undefined behavior.  This code is guaranteed to produce either `1` or `2`.  In a case of true undefined behavior, it could produce other values, or crash, or corrupt open files leaving the computer unbootable, etc.

Comment: Please realize that `x = ++i + ++i;` is undefined behavior, but `int inc(int& v) { return ++v; }` then `x = inc(i) + inc(i);` is not undefined behavior, since accesses to the variable can no longer overlap.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt Sorry, I have not understood your deep idea. I am sure that there is undefined behaviour and his example demonstrates it very clear. His compiler at first evaluates the left operand. As the result m.find(5) != m.end(). Neither prevents the compiler at first to evaluate the right operand. in this case the result will be another.

Comment: Let us replace his `if` statement with `if (rand() < RAND_MAX/2)`  Is that now undefined behavior?  No, it is not.  That a piece of code can give different results does not mean that it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Your example has nothing common with the original code.

Comment: Your argument was that because two results are possible, the behavior is undefined.  That is not true, and I gave a counter-example.  Read this definition: "1.3.25 unspecified behavior -- behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation [ Note: The implementation is not  required to document which behavior occurs. The range of possible behaviors is usually delineated by this International Standard. — end note ]"  That perfectly describes this case.  *Unspecified*, not *undefined*.

Comment: @Ben Voigt You did not show a counter example.As the result depends on the order of the evaluation of operands and the order is unspecified then the behaviour is undefined. You are unable to say what will be the result. Moreover the compiler is allowed in the same program to select different orders of the evaluation of operands. So for the same expression in different parts of the program you can get different results. Is such a behaviour defined?!

Comment: Yes, it is defined as "indeterminately sequenced".  Here is a quote from the Standard: "Every evaluation in the calling function  (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function."  Here the operations are a call to `map::operator[]()` and a call to `map::find()`.  They are indeterminately sequenced.  This does NOT trigger the rule for undefined behavior (continued...)

Comment: The rule for undefined behavior is "If a side effect on a scalar
object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."  These two function calls are sequenced indeterminately (can happen in either order), but they are not unsequenced (can happen simultaneously/intermingled).

Comment: @Ben Voigt There is no function calls. There is the assignment operator.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I am sure that there is undefined behaviour. If you write such a programs with as you think with defined behaviour then I will not advice somebody to use your programs because even you yourself will be unable to say what will be the result. Have a nice day..

Comment: Of course there are function calls.  What do you think that `m.find(5)` is?  What do you think that `m[5]` is?  Both of them are function calls.  BTW `m.find(5)` depends on the structure of the map, which this assignment operator does not change.

Comment: Having different results because of unsequenced behavior like this is not a good thing, and I try not to write programs this way.  But I will downvote answers that confuse "unspecified behavior" and "undefined behavior".  This code is indeterminately sequenced, not unsequenced.  And the behavior is indeterminate, not undefined.